# Can't access Azure SQL DB from my machine using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-sql-database

I created the my own database in azure which is now doesn't have any data. I follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/single-database-create-quickstart?tabs=azure-portal) documentation to create the DB. I want to create table and access it from my machine using python. Here what I tried so far

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

# Obtain connection string information from the portal
config = {
    'host': '<servername>.database.windows.net',
    'user': '<username>@servername.database.windows.net',
    'password': '<passwword>',
    'database': '<DB name>'
}
# Construct connection string
try:
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    print("Connection established")
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Something is wrong with the user name or password")
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("Database does not exist")
    else:
        print(err)
```

but when I when i run it its throwing the following error

`9002 (28000): The server name you tried cannot be found: <servername>.database.windows.net. Please check the Username and retry connection. The Username should be in <username@hostname> format.`

I filled the credentials with mine.

Thanks in advance

I can access from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Why I can't access via Python?

Comment: Are you using [Azure SQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/sql-database/) or [Azure MySQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/mysql/)? Both are different! Your code is for MySQL, but you mentioned you followed the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/single-database-create-quickstart?tabs=azure-portal) for SQL to create DB. Most likely that's the issue. Code should be https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-python for SQL. If you want MySQL then create that instead.

Comment: After you created your database did you set the firewall rules?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood `SQL` and `MySQL`. You can check [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-SQL-and-MySQL-or-SQL-Server) the difference between them.

You are trying to access the `SQL` database using `MySQL` connector. That can't be done. You have two solutions here

1. change your DB to `MySQL` check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/quickstart-create-mysql-server-database-using-azure-portal)
2. access using `SQL` code check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-python)

feel free to ask if you need any clarification